# Unable to get Sonarqube running in Jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline

I followed the docs available on :
https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins

However, I cannot get it to work.
First it appears that the docs need updating because the syntax in the example is wrong. In the latest version of declarative pipelines, `steps` is mandatory inside the `stage`-tag. 
Also, the `def`-keyword only gets resolved when it is inside a `script`-tag.

Beside that, when running Jenkinsfile below, I receive a NPE:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.ToolStep$Execution.run(ToolStep.java:150)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.ToolStep$Execution.run(ToolStep.java:133)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:49)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:290)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
  environment {
    scannerHome = tool 'SonarQube Scanner 3.2.0.1227'
  }
  agent {
    node {
      label "master"
    }
  }

  options {
    buildDiscarder logRotator(daysToKeepStr: '7')
  }

  stages {
    stage("Sonarqube analysis") {
      steps {
        withSonarQubeEnv('SonarQube Scanner') {
          bat "${scannerHome}/bin/sonar-scanner"
        }
      }
    }
```

- Jenkins: v2.107.3
- SonarQube Scanner for Jenkins plug-in: v 2.7.1
- SonarQube Scanner: 3.2.0.1227 (set to install automatically in Global Tool Config)
- Running the job on master (Windows Server 2012 R2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it with the following:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    node {
      label "master"
    }
  }

  stages {
    stage("SonarQube analysis") {
       steps {
          script {
              def sonarScanner = tool name: 'SonarQube', type: 'hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation'
              bat "${sonarScanner}/bin/sonar-scanner -e -Dsonar.host.url=xxx"
            }
         }
      }
    }
  }
```